# How can I write values from several lists to a new csv file?

Tags: java, opencsv

I am trying to create a new csv file which each of its columns will get the values from a different list.
For example, the first column will have all the values of the first list, the second column will have all the values of the second list.

```
    public void writeDataAtOnce()
{

    File workingDirectory = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    String path = workingDirectory + "/src/csv/";
    String csvFile = path + "CsvOutput.csv";
    try {
        FileWriter outputfile = new FileWriter(csvFile);
        CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(outputfile);
        List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<>();
        data.add(new String[] {String.valueOf(firstColumn)});
        data.add(new String[] {String.valueOf(secondColumn)});
        writer.writeAll(data);
        writer.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I managed to write row after row but I need to write to the columns.
This is the result:

```
"A","B","C"
"35"
"19"
"33"
"31"
"25"
"45"
"16"
```

But what I want to do is to have the second list on column "B". Now both lists are in column "A"
How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not see clearly it from the code, but instead of

```java
data.add(new String[] {String.valueOf(firstColumn)});
data.add(new String[] {String.valueOf(secondColumn)});
```

I think that you want to do something like that:

```java
data.add(new String[] {String.valueOf(firstColumn), String.valueOf(secondColumn)});
```

Answer (score 0):

if both lists have equal length...

```
List<String> firstColumn = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> secondColumn = new ArrayList<>();

//TODO add data to lists
int size = firstColumn.size();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
   data.add(new String[] {firstColumn.get(i), secondColumn.get(i)});
}
```